# Checkout page shipping Address form edit Magento2

Tags: checkout, magento2

I need help for Magento 2.x shipping Address fields.

I want to change the Address label text using my new Label text.

Is there anyone you who have changed the Address Label text by own Lable Text.  Could anyone please give the file path and where I can change the text for Checkout page Shipping address fields.

Please Take a look my screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the path where you can edit Address label text:

`app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

Answer (score 1):

**Following will be helpful**

**step 1 :**
      If you want to change the shipping address fields as well as billing address fields, You can do via theme transaction if you have made a custom theme as per your language.

> i.e: en_US

**Step 2 :**
      If you change made in shipping address fields only, Please override LayoutProcessor.php

**step 2.1**

*di.xml*

> path: app/code/vendor/module_name/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="Custom_Checkout" type="vendor\module_name\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

Step 2:
*LayoutProcessor.php*

> path:app/code/vendor/module_name/Block/

```
         public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['label'] = __('Recipient lastname'); 

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['region_id']['label'] = __('Division'); 

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**It's work like charm**